# Problem with items overlapping when resizing window

Tags: javascript, css, sass, responsive

I've tried a lot of things but can't seem to achieve what I need...the goal is to avoid the list items (sidebar items) to overlap with the menu toggle when I resize the window's height.

Anyone can help me with this?

Here is the code in a CodePen so you can visualise it:

[CodePen Sidebar Menu](https://codepen.io/sandropolixe/pen/LYgQzqB)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@300&display=swap');
*{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

}
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(
        to left, #43c6ac, #191654
    );
}

.navigation{
    position: fixed;
    inset: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    width: 75px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;

    .menuToggle{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 0 23px;

        &::before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #333;
            transform: translateY(-8px);
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        &::after{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #333;
            transform: translateY(8px);
            transition: 0.5s;
            box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 #333;

        }

    }
    ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        width: 100%;

        li{
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            
            &.active{
                transform: translateX(30px);

                a{
                    .icon{
                        color: #fff;
                        background: var(--clr);
                        &::before{
                            opacity: 0.5;
                        }
                    }
                    .text{
                        color: var(--clr);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            a{
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;

                .icon{
                    position: relative;
                    display: block;
                    min-width: 55px;
                    height: 55px;
                    line-height: 60px;
                    transition: 0.5s;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    font-size: 1.75em;
                    color: #222;
                    &::before{
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 10px;
                        left: 0px;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        background: var(--clr);
                        filter: blur(8px);
                        opacity: 0;
                        transition: 0.5s;

                    }
                }
                .text{
                    position: relative;
                    padding: 0 15px;
                    height: 60px;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    color: #333;
                    opacity: 0;
                    visibility: hidden;
                    transition: 0.5s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &.open .menuToggle::before{
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(45deg);

    }
    &.open{
        width: 250px;
    }
    &.open .menuToggle::after{
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
    }
    &.open ul li.active{
        transform: translateX(15px);
    }
    &.open ul li a .text{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

I tried to modify the SCSS file and add some snippets but with my limited experience I failed to fix the problem.

Comment: You have given fixed width to the sidebar that's why it will not change on small screen. Use media queries to adjust the width or height or any css property for any screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add below css with media query to target mobile devices on your `.navigation.open` class.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
       .navigation.open {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS .navigation has a width from 75px. It means on every Breakpoint it has the same size. If you want that the menue get thinner or bigger you need to replace it with a percentual size and handle the rest like this. But work with [max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.php#:%7E:text=The%20max%2Dwidth%20property%20defines,width%20property%20has%20no%20effect.).